# @aws-amplify/ui-components - Trigger Toast with Custom Message

Tags: aws-amplify

I'm using `@aws-amplify/ui-components` library which is deprecated (for Vue 2). It comes with a Toast component (`<amplfy-toast />`)which alerts error messages in the top of the screen. In my Vue js component I want to trigger  message but programatically where the `console.log()` is:

```
    watch: {
        authState: {
            async handler(state) {
                const data = this.authData
                if (state === 'signedin') {
                    try {
                        const local = await this.axios.post('/api/v1/authentication/login', {
                            token: data.getSignInUserSession().getIdToken().getJwtToken()
                        })
                        if ( ! local.data.error) {
                            await this.$store.dispatch('login', data)
                        }
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error) // Trigger toast here.
                    }
                }
            },
            immediate: true
        }
    },
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `dispatchToastHubEvent()` function or simply call:

```
Hub.dispatch('UI Auth', {
    event: 'ToastAuthError',
    message: error.message
})
```